# Remote validation restrict for edit controller method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, remote-validation

I have model for register

my model class

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{


    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a minimum of {2} characters", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DisplayName("University ID")]
    [Remote("doesusernameExist", "HEC",null, ErrorMessage = "usr name is allready exist", HttpMethod = "POST")]
    public string usrname { get; set; }    }
```

my json controller class

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult doesusernameExist(string usrname)
    {

         var institute = db.Institutes.Find(HEI_ID);
                   return Json(institute == null);


    }
```

for create new user and edit user I'm using above model . so without create another model , I want to disable doesusernameExist calling method in edit method

Comment: You either need 2 view models (best solution), or you need to pass an additional value to the `doesusernameExist()` method (say the ID property) using the `AdditionalFields` property of `RemoteAttribute` so that you can use that to conditionally test if the database check needs to be performed (i.e. if the ID is null or zero its a new object, so `return Json(true);` or whatever logic you want to apply)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First in Edit View disable client side validation for `username`:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.username, new { @data_val = "false" })
```

Second in Edit Post Action remove validation result for `username` from `ModelState`:

```
public ActionResult EditUser([Bind(Exclude = "usrname")]RegisterViewModel model)
{
    ModelState.Remove("username");
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: This removes all validation including the `[Required]` and `[StringLength]` validation!

Comment: Of course it removes all validations but in `Edit User Action` there is no need to check username because it's already exists and user cannot change his/her username. it's obvious, isn't it ?

Comment: You have shown a textbox so the user can edit it. So the user clears the contents of the textbox or edits it to more than 100 characters or edits it to be the same as some other users 'username', all of which are invalid but wont be picked up.

Comment: If look at the answer carefully `[Bind(Exclude = "usrname")]` solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

First Add a Hidden field in View as:

```
@Html.hidden("PreviousUsername", Model.usrname)
```

In your .cs class add following:

```
[Remote("doesusernameExist", "HEC", ErrorMessage = "usr name is allready exist", AdditionalFields = "PreviousUsername")]
public string usrname { get; set; }
```

An your controller Action Method should be like:

```
public JsonResult doesusernameExist(string usrname, string PreviousUsername)
{

     if(usrname==PreviousUsername)
     {
       return true;
     }
     var institute = db.Institutes.Find(HEI_ID);
     return Json(false, JsonAlloBehaviour.AllowGet);

}
```

Comment: This worked well for me because I have one form that does both New & Edit.